# Word Wrap in Gridviews with Linq DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, linq, gridview

I'm having an issue with word wrapping a Gridview. The source for the Gridview is a Linq Source that is built in the LinqDataSourceLog_Selecting method. I have a column that I want to word wrap but I guess because of how I am binding the Gridview, the Column count is Always 0 so I can't wrap something I don't have. The following is the markup for the Grid.

```
                                <asp:GridView ID="GridViewLog" Width="200px" runat="server" CellPadding="4" AllowPaging="true"
                                DataSourceID="LinqDataSourceLog" ShowHeader="true" AllowSorting="true" OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewLog_PageIndexChanging"
                                EnableModelValidation="True" AutoGenerateColumns="true" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Both" 
                                Height="164px" OnRowDataBound="GridViewLog_RowDataBound" RowStyle-Wrap="true" AlternatingRowStyle-Wrap="true"
                                PageSize="10" PagerSettings-Mode="Numeric" OnPreRender="GridViewLog_Prerender">
                                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="color: #003366">
                                                <strong>Either the applied filter returned no results or<br />
                                                    the Out of office log is currently empty .</strong>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" Wrap="false" />
                                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                                <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" CssClass="pagination" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" Wrap="false" />
                                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                            </asp:GridView>
```

thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Count property for the Columns collection in a grid view only counts the number of declared columns you have specified in the markup.  When you specify `AutoGenerateColumns="true"`, those columns will not be counted.

As an alternative to `GridViewLog.Columns.Count`, what is the result you get when you use `GridViewLog.HeaderRow.Cells.Count`?  That should tell you the count of all columns, auto generated or not.

Comment: Very nice. I get the correct number of columns, however I'm not able to wrap the column still. I tried     GridViewLog.HeaderRow.Cells[6].Wrap = true; but to no avail.